# Is there an error in my Code using iTextSharp and WPF DataGrid to export PDF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, itext

I have been trying this code to export my DataGrid Data to PDF with iTextSharp I downloaded from Nuget, but when I clicked the ExportToPdf button nothing happens, seems like empty Click Event and no compilation error occured. I tried going through many Solutions here, but still didn't work.
Hare is my Xaml:

```
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AMD.Views"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Customers Page" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <!--<Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="b" Value=""  />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>-->

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="GeneratePDF"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}"
    Width="120" ToolTip="Generate PDF" Margin="10 10 20 10"
    Click="GeneratePDF_Click">
                Export As PDF
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgvCustomers" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CustomerName, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Customer Name"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DateBought, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Date Bought"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Item Name" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Price, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Price"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Quantity"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SubTotal, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Sub Total"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Total, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Total"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ReducedPrice, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Discount"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PaymentType, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Payment Type"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Cash, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Cash"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Transfer, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Transfer"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Bank, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Bank"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Comment, TargetNullValue=------}" Header="Comment"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and C#:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace AMD.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CustomersPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CustomersPage : Page
    {
        public CustomersPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var db = new AMDDataContext();
            var query = from p in db.Customers
                        select p;

            dgvCustomers.ItemsSource = query;

            var query1 = from p in db.Customers
                         where  p.DateBought.Value != null
                        select p;

            //CustomersByDate.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();
            //CustomersByDate.DisplayMemberPath = "DateBought";
            //CustomersByDate.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

            CustomersSelectionType.Items.Add("Daily");
            CustomersSelectionType.Items.Add("Weekly");
            CustomersSelectionType.Items.Add("Monthly");
            CustomersSelectionType.Items.Add("Yearly");
        }

        private void GeneratePDF_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dgvCustomers.Columns.Count);

            Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new System.IO.FileStream("Test.pdf",
                System.IO.FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();

            for (int j = 0; j < dgvCustomers.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(dgvCustomers.Columns[j].Header.ToString()));
            }
            table.HeaderRows = 1;
            IEnumerable itemsSource = dgvCustomers.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
            if (itemsSource != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in itemsSource)
                {
                    DataGridRow row = dgvCustomers.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
                        for (int i = 0; i < dgvCustomers.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                            TextBlock txt = cell.Content as TextBlock;
                            if (txt !=null)
                            {
                                table.AddCell(new Phrase(txt.Text));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                doc.Add(table);
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        private T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                    return (T)child;
                else
                {
                    T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                    if (childOfChild != null)
                        return childOfChild;
                }
            }
                return null;
        }

    }
}
```

No error in the Code, but it does nothing. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: There are things that can be improved, but a quick test shows that it is working. A PDF is generated with the contents of the data grid. Try to set an absolute path for the `FileStream` like `C:\Any\Path\Test.pdf`. Maybe the file is not generated where you think it is.

Comment: How can I let dialog open to choose where to save the file? Help please.

Comment: Why not test it with a hard-coded path? A dialog adds unnecessary complexity and further potential issues rather than helping to solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yesss! as @thatguy said, it works. After some searches on my Computer I found that it was saved in the Debug Folder of my Project. Thank You @thatguy.